# C - File Input/Validation LINUX/Windows Issue

Tags: c, windows, linux, validation, file-io

```
FILE *f;

char buffer[201];   
f=fopen("file.txt","r");

if (f==NULL)
{ 
    printf("file doesn't exist?!\n");return 1;
}

while(1)
{
    if ((fgets(buffer, 200, f) == NULL)) 
        break;

    instruction = validatehex(buffer);
    if(instruction == - 1) 
        continue;

    PC += 4;
    Decode(instruction,verbose);
}
```

The above code gets the input from the file line by line validating it.
The problem is in the validatehex function it always prints "Not correct" even if the value is correct. This code works 100% perfect in windows put not in linux(Ubuntu).

```
uint32_t validatehex(char input[])
{
    char hexchars[] = "1234567890abcdefABCDEF";
    uint32_t hexvalue = 0;
    char last;
    if((strlen(input) != strspn (input,hexchars)) && ((strlen(input)-1 != strspn (input,hexchars)) &&  input[8] != '\0'))
    {
        printf("NO CORRECT\n"); 
        return INERR;
    }

    sscanf(input,"%08x",&hexvalue);
    return hexvalue;
}
```

I've tried it across to windows with mingw32 c compiler and it works perfect. 
The file it reads from just consists of hex values which are 8 digits long on each line.

Can anyone see where the code is going wrong? Or why it is working differently within Linux?

Comment: too_______many_______________spaces_______________please_____remove_________them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux and Windows use different end-of-line markers: Windows uses `\r\n` while Linux uses `\n`.  What kind of linebreaks does your file use?

If you are reading a file written in windows on Linux, you will get an extra `\r` at the end of the string.

This is one way to avoid the problem:

```
int len = strlen(input);
if (input[len-1] == '\r') input[len-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: In the file its just the enter key used between the lines? and in the code its input[8] != '\0' to check if the 9th character is a new line, if "\n" is the new line in windows why would the 9th character be "\0" and it work fine in windows...

Comment: @user983969 in Windows when you write `\n` to a file the OS translates it to `\r\n`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: So i should replace the \0 to \n and that would work corectly?

Comment: Replacing the \0 which checks if the last character is a new line characer with \n still doenst work correctly in linux but still fine in linux

Comment: No, since the `\n` is never copied to the string that wouldn't work.  You could check if the final character of the string is `\r` instead.

Comment: @user983969 you won't find an `\r` at the end of the string in windows, so you have to check for `\0` as well

Comment: So if i was using the code between both platforms , am i bes to just check for "\r" and replace it with a \0 in linux like your code above? and that should work on both platforms ?